# Joining the serialization of two forms and then POST the values to an URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two forms;

When the formTwo submit button is pressed using jQuery i serialize all the vars from form one and form two:

```
$('#formTwo').submit(function(e){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert( $('#formOne').serialize() + '&' +  $('#formTwo').serialize() );
});
```

All this works ok, now how can I POST all the vars serialized to an URL without AJAX (just old fashion synchronized web call )?

**I cant merge the forms into one** (technical limitations), eventually i could change the event to GET instead of POST and just do a redirect to the `URL + '?' + serializedVars` but i prefer to solve this using POST.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a form dynamically, append all the serialized stuff as hidden fields and 
append it to document body and then do the submit from JavaScript.